# How to make an Array of Strings with no values yet

Tags: java, string, android-studio

In my program the user will introduce a string(String A) and I want an Array(AA[]) of Strings to get every single letter of the String A. But it says that the Array

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class arrays{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String A,B,AA[];
        int a,cX,cY,cc,c;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce your text");
        A=scanner.nextLine();
        a=A.length();
        cX=0;
        cY=cX+1;
        cc=0;
        for(c=0;c==a;c++){
            B=A.substring(cX,cY);
            AA[cc]=B;
            cc+=cc;
            cX+=cX;
            cY+=cY;
        }
    }
}
```

It says(The error), that the variable AA might no have been initialized.
   What I want is to make the Array to have all the letters from the String A...

**UPDATED:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class arrays{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String A,B,AA[];
        int a,cX,cY,cc,c;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce your text");
        A=scanner.nextLine();
        a=A.length();
        cX=0;
        cY=cX+1;
        cc=0;
        AA = new String[a];
        for(c=0;c==a;c++){
            B=A.substring(cX,cY);
            AA[cc]=B;
            cc+=cc;
            cX+=cX;
            cY+=cY;
        }
        System.out.println(AA[2]);
    }
}
```

Now when I print it out, it says null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize AA to the length of String A:

```
AA = new String[A.length];
```

And your loop is strange. You can change it to :

```
    for(c=0;c<a;c++){
        B=A.substring(c,c+1);
        AA[c]=B;
    }
```

Comment: @ANDDEV I edited my answer with a suggested way to fix the loop.

Comment: @ANDDEV `String B` is not needed. Simply do `AA[c] = A.substring(c, c+1)`. But, if you feel you must use it, the best thing is to minimize its scope. It seems this String is only used in the for() loop, so you should declare it there like so `String B=A.substring(c,c+1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
Instance and class variables are initialized to null (or 0), but local variables are not.
```

A local variable must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization or assignment

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String inputString; //A
   char [] inputStringCharacters; //AA

   Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Introduce your text");
   inputString=scanner.nextLine();

   inputStringCharacters = new char[inputString.length()];

   for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
   {
       inputStringCharacters[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
   }

   //print each character in AA
   for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
   {
       System.out.println(inputStringCharacters[i]);
   }
}
```

I also strongly advise you to use descriptive variable names rather than things like "cc, A, AA", etc. It will be much easier to understand the logic of your code if you make it clear what a variable is supposed to contain.

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to use `inputString.toCharArray()` instead of filling the array manually? Especially if you want to show "easier" stuff?

Comment: Yes, it would. I missed that one.